# How do I stop a python script from running via a webpage?

Tags: python, php

So I have a a webpage that has buttons to run a script that controls a PIR sensor and an LED.
How do I stop the script from running using a second button?

Button 1 : Run sensor.py
Button 2 : Stop sensor.py script

I've looked up on it, and it seems that I need to find the PID, how would I do it via a web interface?

Regards

**SensorON.py**

```
while True(sensor value):
sensing code
turn led on()
print('motion detected')

elif os.path.exists('/var/www/gpio/SensorOff.py'):
    print 'stop-script detected'
    os.remove('/var/www/gpio/SensorOff.py')
    print 'stop-script deleted - now exiting'
    exit();

else
turn off led()
print('no motion detected')
```

**Web page**

```
if (isset($_POST['SensorON']))
{
exec('sudo python /var/www/SensorON.py');
}

if (isset($_POST['SensorOFF']))
{
exec('sudo touch /var/www/SensorOFF.py');
}
```

Comment: You wrote a script to do "button 1". So why not write another script, bind it to "button 2" and let that kill the first script? Either using `pidof` or let the first script create a pid-file.

Comment: @Wilf I haven't tried, I've only searched on various forums about it. Wasn't sure where to start.

-Ghanima I wasn't sure how to find the PID and reference it in the button 2 script.  I'll take a look on how to use that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the best way to do this is to have the running script periodically check for some flag that is set via the other script.  One easy way to do that is to have the running script check for the existence of a file (`stop-script`, for example) which normally doesn't exist.

Then all you need to do in the script that is run when the `Stop Button` is pressed is to create (or `touch`) the file `stop-script`.

The running script should then delete the `stop-script` file just before it exits setting up for the next execution of the running script.

Here's what I envision in pseudo code (using python indentation for blocks):

**sensor.py Script**

```
while( TRUE )
  -- code to check sensor

  if exists '/path/to/stop-script'
     continue # exit while loop

  sleep(5)    # sleep for 5 seconds

print 'stop-script file detected'
delete file '/path/to/stop-script'
print 'stop-script file deleted - we will now exit'
```

**button-2-pressed.py Script**

```
execute_os_command("touch /path/to/stop-script")
```

Something like that.

**Update: Answer to 2nd problem, namely web page hangs when running main script**

Your second issue is that when in PHP you run `exec('sudo python /var/www/SensorON.py');` , PHP will wait for the command to terminate, which in your case doesn't happen until later.  You need to make this command run "asynchronously", see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php) for more detail, but effectively you need the following in your PHP web page:

```
if (isset($_POST['SensorON']))
{
    exec('sudo python /var/www/SensorON.py > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
}

if (isset($_POST['SensorOFF']))
{
    exec('sudo touch /var/www/SensorOFF.py');
}
```

By adding `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` to the command string redirects the output of the Python program to `/dev/null` ([the bit bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_bucket)) and most importantly the final "`&`" character causes Python to run as a separate process and return is immediately returned to PHP allowing your web page to complete.

Comment: So while the button 1 script is running,  it also checks for another python script? (Which is run when button 2 is pressed)
Sorry I didn't get the second part, could you please clarify why the running script needs to delete the stop-script.

Comment: I'll give it a go and let you know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: Okay Im stuck, how would I create the stop-script file from the press of a button?
I usually call it from a known location :
if (isset($_POST['SensorOn']
exec('sudo python /var/www/SensorOn.py');
I've no idea how to actually create a script within one.

Comment: When button 2 is pressed you want to run ' button-2-pressed.py' which should already exist and contain the commands to create the stop file.  You could also just run 
`exec('touch /path/to/stop-script')` to shell out and create the file directly.  The path to the file could also be /tmp which will ensure that the file is deleted upon reboot.

Comment: Alright , works a treat! Appreciate the help.

Comment: Another problem has just come up!
While the first button is presssed, it runs the sensor.py script, the second button on the same page is unable to be pressed as it's continuously running the first script. Is there a work around this?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Added to description above

Comment: What does the file exists test code look like in `SensorON.py`?  FYI, I didn't intend for the `touch` command to create a `.py` file, just an empty file with any name.  The flag file name could just be `/tmp/bozo` and the SensorON.py script would just check to see if `/tmp/bozo` existed or not.  Get the idea?

Comment: I just named it for the sake of readability, similar to that of the SensorOn.py script. Updated with code.